# RecyclerView with SwipeRefreshLayout + CoordinatorLayout with Menu

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, slidingmenu, android-coordinatorlayout, slidingdrawer

So I've been facing this weird problem with `RecyclerView` scroll.

Let me first tell you about my requirements:

1. I need to have a menu above the `ToolBar`. Sort of like a sliding
   drawer layout that opens from top when a button is clicked. I
   achieved this by creating a custom sliding drawer. This drawer
   visibility is set to GONE at the beginning. When the user clicks on
   the menu icon, the visibility is set to VISIBILE.
2. A `CoordinatorLayout` with `ToolBar` which includes a menu button.
3. A parallax image below the `ToolBar` which shrinks when scrolled.
4. A `SwipeToRefreshLayout` with `RecyclerView` inside.

I am facing two problems:

- `RecyclerView` scroll is not at all smooth. When I scroll to the
  bottom, the list item is only visible after a second. It gets stuck
  in between when scrolling the first time. I'm sure there must be
  something that be done to scroll smoothly.
- When I click on the menu icon, the menu layout is visible. Once it is
  hidden again, part of the `RecyclerView` is completely gone. Not sure
  why. Please find screenshot below on this problem

**Look at Screenshoots**

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

- The first screenshot is the normal look
- The second screenshot is of the menu layout
- The third screenshot is what happens after the menu is closed

I am completely helpless on how to fix this, so any help is appreciated.

### My layout code is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.app.ranky.menu.Transparent
        android:id="@+id/popup_window"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left">

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#320d77"
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_large"
                android:id="@+id/menu_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_large"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_large"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:shrinkColumns="*"
                android:stretchColumns="*"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin"
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent">

                        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ic_whatsapp"
                            android:id="@+id/id_whatsapp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ic_fb"
                            android:id="@+id/id_fb"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


                        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ic_mail"
                            android:id="@+id/id_mail"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"/>

                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </com.app.ranky.menu.Transparent>

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="183dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/header"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_banner"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_slidemenu"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:id="@+id/slide_menu_btn"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <com.app.ranky.views.CustomTextView
                                android:paddingRight="45dp"
                                android:text="@string/app_name"
                                android:id="@+id/app_title"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                android:textSize="18dp"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="#cfccd8"
                                app:font="circular_book" />

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_gravity="right"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding"
                                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_large"
                                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_large"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <ImageButton
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_small"
                                     android:background="@drawable/add_app_circle"
                                    android:id="@+id/app_add_btn"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <com.app.ranky.views.CustomSwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:behavior_overlapTop="30dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/listOfferItems"
                    android:listSelector="#00000000"
                    android:fadingEdge="none" android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
                    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"/>

            </com.app.ranky.views.CustomSwipeRefreshLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

### The transparent class is basically just a linearLayout class:

```
public class Transparent extends LinearLayout {

    public Transparent(Context context, AttributeSet as) {
        super(context, as);
    }

    public Transparent(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. How about this? Can I add a CoordinatorLayout as a child of LinearLayout? No one seems to have done that and I think this issue is because it is one of the children of LinearLayout (The other being the sliding drawer)

Comment: So I got the scroll issue fixed by using a a custom implementation of LinearLayoutManager and overriding the smoothScrollToPosition. still working on fixing the second issue. Any help in the right direction is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I fixed it using this code:

appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, false);

It was because the appBarLayout was expanding when the menu was displayed.